# Is there a pattern that when sliced into bread dough - causes the bread to be fairly level?

Tags: bread

When I bake bread, every loaf tens to swell in the center and each end of the loaf is smaller.  The result is that sandwiches cut from different sections of the loaf vary dramatically in size.

I asked a question on this forum about a bread lame and a commenter mentioned that slices in bread dough changes how the bread swells during baking.   Is there a pattern, that when sliced into dough, causes the bread to not swell so much in the center?   So that there is not as large a variation in bread slices cut from one end to the other?

Comment: You might want to get a Pullman pan, if you’re concerned with consistent slice sizes

Comment: What's the shape of your dough (long, ball)? What kind of fermentation  (sourdough, leavened)? How much hydration? Those can also influence the rise (I haven't seen a foccacia that doesn't rise fairly uniformly, for example, and it's not scored at all)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is a standard white loaf with close crumb, would be known as Toastbrot in Germany  ie nice even slices.

Either 3 equal tightly rolled balls or a 3 strand braid (ends tucked under) in the loaf tin, will help the raising to be more even.

For truly flat top, tin needs a lid.

For a nice 'M' top, a knife or better, a metal scraper, dipped in oil, is poked lengthwise to a depth of an inch.
Helps a bit with evenness of top but mostly it prevents sides from ripping.

Answer (score -2):

For consistent bread shape, especially for sandwiches, you need to use a bread/loaf baking pan.

The pan sides will restrict the bread to rise in one direction only in a more uniform fashion.